# HowTo check whether Exception Block is available for the main PLSQL block or routine

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g

I am trying to think of a validator that checks for Exception block available in PL/SQL block or any routine for the main body ( Highlighted in Bold).

Eg :

```
DECLARE
some data
      Procedure xyx IS
      BEGIN
      ....
      EXCEPTION
      ..
      END;  

BEGIN
some data
      BEGIN
      ....
      EXCEPTION
      ..
      END;  
**EXCEPTION**
some data
      BEGIN
      ....
      EXCEPTION
      ..
      END; 
END;
```

This is a simple example there can be many other scenarios but my need id to find that Exception block is avaialble for the main block of PL/SQL code.

Please let me know if you have any suggestion.
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Are you trying to write a PL/SQL parser?  Why would you want to check to see whether a particular block has an exception handler?  Most blocks shouldn't.

Comment: Its mere to check for that block. A sort of validation only.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Unix box and have GNU awk present, you can try this:

```
$ awk '/Procedure/ || p==1{if (/END/)p=0;else p=1;next}/BEGIN/{f++;next}/END/{f--;next}/EXCEPTION/ && f==1{print "Exception present"}' IGNORECASE=1 file.sql
```

Comment: Thanks Bu tI am looking for a sql query or a pl sql code to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you **want** an exception handler in every program unit?

In my opinion it is best to handle only exception which make business sense and are somewhat planned and let **all other errors and problems bubble up** to the application.

Consider using

> begin 
>   exception 
>   end

blocks so that the exception block for the planned exception has a small scope. Also avoid large exception blocks at the end of large program units.

Most exception blocks I saw in the wild do some logging and either rise the exception or swallow it entirely thereby destroying the stacktrace or the occurrence of the problem itself.

If you think you must log a technical exception then please use dbms_utility.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK and write something useful.